# How to I add an edit event to this angular js application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please, I have this block of code and I'm at a loss on how to add an edit event and button. Any help please?

```
<script>
  var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
  firstApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
    $scope.toic = '';
    $scope.discussion = '';
    $scope.updateMessage = function() {
      $scope.heading = $scope.topic;
      $scope.body = $scope.discussion;
    };
  });
</script>
<input ng-model="topic">
<input ng-model="discussion">
<button ng-click="updateMessage()">click<button>

<div>
{{heading}} 
{{Body}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there! The stackoverflow community enjoys helping out developers achieve their goals, with the premise of helping one's self first. In that regard, have a look at this [link][1] to help you better formulate your question, show your work and help us help you in general. Thanks!


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have no `ng-app` or `ng-controller` attributes, so no bindings will happen. Try wrapping your inputs and your div with `<div ng-app="firstApp" ng-controller="FirstController">`

Comment: Also, `$scope.toic` will not be displayed in your input being bound to `topic` as they are not spelled the same

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you have a few typos and missing information that is causing this to not work:

1) You need to wrap your HTML in an element that has `ng-app` and `ng-controller` attributes so angular knows which module/controller to use for the logic in your bindings.

2) `$scope.toic` should be `$scope.topic`

3) `{{Body}}` should be `{{body}}`

4) `<button ...><button>` should be `<button ...></button>` (missing `/` on closing tag)

```js
var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
firstApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
  $scope.topic = '';
  $scope.discussion = '';
  $scope.updateMessage = function() {
    $scope.heading = $scope.topic;
    $scope.body = $scope.discussion;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="firstApp" ng-controller="FirstController">
  <input ng-model="topic">
  <input ng-model="discussion">
  <button ng-click="updateMessage()">click</button>

  <div>{{heading}} 
  {{body}} </div>
</div>
```